# Is Retrofit2 API end point safe to be shared among multiple threads

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have the following Retrofit2 API end point.

```
Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
MyApi myApi = retrofit.create(MyApi.class);
// Is retrofit2 API end point safe to shared among different threads?
return myApi;
```

I was wondering, is Retrofit2 API end point thread safe? Is it safe to be shared among multiple threads?